# How to properly initialize a .NET OleDbConnection object and its ConnectionString property?

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string, oledb, oledbconnection

This is my C# code to connect and work with an Access database.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

var cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Customer"].NewRow();

dRow[0] = textBox1.Text;
dRow[1] = textBox2.Text;
dRow[2] = textBox3.Text;

ds1.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Add(dRow);

da.Update(ds1, "Customer");

con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Entry added");
```

But the line `da.Update(ds1,"Customer");`, throws an exception:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: Where are you initializing your connection object? Show us, but probably you haven't set any connection strings for it.

Comment: If it's a connection string issue, look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your question too well, but here's some sample code that may help you figure out whatever it is that you are trying to do.

For clarity: The database is named "MyDb.accdb" and has a table named "Customer" which has two fields "Name" and "Phone". This example assumes the database lives in the same directory as the executable.

```
private void AddCustomer(string customerName, string customerPhone)
{
    string name = customerName;
    string phone = customerPhone;

    // An easy way to determine the connection string to your database is to open the database from Visual Studio's 'Server Explorer'.
    // Then, from Server Explorer, view the Properties of the database - in the Properties you will see the "Connection String". 
    // You can/should replace the arbitrary part of the path with "|DataDirectory|".
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

    // Create your sql query in a string variable
    string cmdText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Customer(Name, Phone) VALUES('{0}','{1}');", name, phone);

    // Use the 'using' statement on your connection so that the resource is managed properly
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString))
    {                
        // Here's where/how we fire off the INSERT statement
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```